# AWS DMS Streaming replication : Logical Decoding Output Plugins(test_decoding) not accessible

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-replication, aws-dms

I'm trying to migrate a PostgreSQL DB persisted on cloud (on DO droplet) to RDS using AWS Database Migration Service (DMS).

I've successfully configured the replication instance and endpoints.

I've created a task with **Migrate existing data and replicate ongoing changes**. When I start the task it shows some error `ERROR:  could not access file "test_decoding": No such file or directory`.

I've tried to create a replication slot manually on my DB console it throws the same error.

I've followed the procedures which was suggested on the [DMS documentation for Postgres](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html)

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.6 on my source endpoint.

I presume that the problem is the output plugin **test_decoding** was not accessible to do the replication.

Please assist me to resolve this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You must install **postgresql-contrib** additional supplied modules on Your source endpoint.

If it is installed, make sure, directory where **test_decoding** module located is the same with directory where PostgreSQL expect it.

In *nix, You can check module directory by command:

```
pg_config --pkglibdir
```

If it is not the same, copy module, or make symlink, or some other solution You prefer.